# Ruby array manipulation inside method

Tags: ruby, local-variables

In the following, `input_1` changes:

```
def method_1(a)
  a << "new value"
end

input_1 = []
method_1(input_1)
input_1 #=> ["new value"]
```

In the following, `input_2` does not change:

```
def method_2(a)
  a = ["new value"]
end

input_2 = []
method_2(input_2)
input_2 #=> []
```

Why does `input_1` change while `input_2` doesn't change?

Comment: What is your question exactly? You expect the value of input to be `['new value']` both times?

Comment: Why changes input_1 whereas input_2 doesn't change?

Comment: the concept is called "mutability". `method_2` simply assignes a new variable with the same name as the other one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With a bit of simplification we can say that a variable in Ruby is a reference to a value. In your case variable `a` holds a reference to an array.

`a <<` (`a.append`) mutates the **value** stored in variable `a`. The reference is not changed, but the value did. It's the case of `method_1`

```
def method_1(a)
    a << "new value"
end
```

Assignment `=` changes the reference stored in a variable - it starts to point to a different value. References are copied when passed to a method. Because of that when you call

```
def method_2(a)
    a = ["new value"]
end
input = []
method_2(a)
```

You only change a reference stored in `a` that is local to the method, without any change to the reference stored in `input` nor to the value (and array of `[]`) that is pointed by this reference.

Comment: Note that if the invocation were changed to `input_2 = method_2(input_2)`, the new reference generated by `method_2` would be assigned to `input_2` since Ruby methods return the result of their last evaluation.

Answer (score 7):

It boils down to Ruby using "pass-reference-by-value".

The exact case that you encounter is described in [this excellent blog post](https://robertheaton.com/2014/07/22/is-ruby-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value/).

#### The gist:

In `method_1` you are changing the value of an object that two different variables (`input_1` and `a`) are both pointing to.

In `method_2` you are reassigning a completely new object to one of the two variables (`a`).

Answer (score 2):

> Why `input_1` changes whereas `input_2` doesn't change?

The *very simple* answer to this question is that your premise is wrong. `input_1` doesn't change. *The object that `input_1` references* changes, but that is something *completely different* from `input_1`. The name of a thing is *not* the same as the thing itself. (Outside of witchcraft.)