# Ruby ! Methods or Procs

Tags: ruby, block, proc

I'm wanting to modify a `variable` in place, replicating the `methodname!` syntax as opposed to reassigning a new modified value to the same `var`.  Can I do this with a `proc`?  I'm still learning `procs` and see them as quite useful is used properly.

```
a = "Santol bag 85.88   www.example.com/products/16785
Shaddock    kg  2.94    www.example.com/products/4109
Palm Fig    5kg 94.34   www.example.com/products/23072
Litchee lb  95.85   www.example.com/products/2557"

a = a.split("\n")

linebreak = Proc.new { |text| text.split("\n") }
linebreak![a]
```

that first reassignment seems cumbersome.  The proc version I would like to see if I can perform it inline.  Is this possible?

Comment: Using a `!` isn't special syntax, it's a naming convention that you can only use when declaring functions -- so `linebreak! = Proc.new...` will cause a syntax error. You also cannot _generally_ mutate out-of-scope state from a `Proc`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`methodname!` is just a convention - usually there are two *flavours* of the same method - one without bang and one with bang. If you want to have a proc that mutates its params, you need to implement it using mutating methods.

And in this case it's not possible, because you're trying to transform a string into an array. You have to reassign the variable:

```
linebreak = Proc.new { |text| text.split("\n") }
a = linebreak.call(a)
```

Comment: So that reassignment to a new type is the caveat?

Comment: Arguments in ruby are passed to methods and procs as values, so you cannot reassign them. See [this detailed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54090261/ruby-array-manipulation-inside-method/54090391#54090391)

Answer (score 7):

This is surely possible, you just need to modify the string inplace

```
linebreak = ->(text) { text.replace text.split("\n").join(",") }
a = "foo\nbar"
linebreak[a]
#⇒ "foo,bar"
a
#⇒ "foo,bar"
```

What is not possible, is to change the class in place, that’s why `split` won’t work (called on a string, it returns an array.)

Comment: This does work, but as a caveat, it's not a great design choice _because_ it mutates state and doesn't feature a bang (`!`) in the name -- which could lead future programmers to believe it's a function without side-effects.

Comment: @Jules that’s ruby; everything should be considered mutable. Also, you might notice `String#replace` from stdlib used above does not have a bang in its name.

Comment: The `!` is a convention that is *only* used for *pairs* of methods, and *not* only used for mutation. E.g. `Process::exit!` has nothing to do with mutation, and `String#clear` doesn't have a bang.