# Why are changes to arrays in methods persistent, while changes to integers are not

Tags: ruby

```
aa = 5
bb = [5]

def change(x,y)
  x = x + 5
  y[0] = y[0] + 5
  puts "Done"
end

change(aa, bb)
p aa 
#=> 5
p bb
#=> [10]
```

After calling the change method using the arguments `aa` and `bb`, the value of `bb` has changed and value of `aa` has not changed.

Can anyone explain why the value of `bb` has changed and the value of `aa` has not changed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ruby array manipulation inside method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54090261/ruby-array-manipulation-inside-method)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first line:

```
x = x + 5
```

assigns a new value to the variable `x`. The new value is valid only in the current variable scope, i.e. within the method.

The second line:

```
y[0] = y[0] + 5
```

also looks like an assignment, but it isn't. `y[0] = ...` is syntactic sugar for the method call [`Array#[]=`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/Array.html#method-i-5B-5D-3D) which modifies the array.

So unlike the first line, the second line doesn't change the variable – `y` still refers to the very same object afterwards. It's the object that has been changed, not the variable. Therefore, the change is visible from the outside.

Answer (score 0):

1. Array is mutable object, when you do `array_object << somevalue` it actually modify the existing array
2. when you do assignment inside the method, it creates/changes the variable in local scope, that means it won't change/effect variable declared out side of your method.

Now in your case array is not being changed by assignment, it's being changed by `<<` operator

To verify this you can use following code

```
aa = 5
bb = [5]

def change(x,y)
  x = x + 5
  y = y + [5]
  puts "Done #{x}  #{y}"
end

change(aa, bb)
p aa # Output 5
p bb # Output [5] <= not changed because we didn't use << operator
```

You will se it will change the value and print new value inside the method body, but outside the method body it will still print the old values (because of the point #1 I mentioned above.)